# How to load a CSV (or TSV) into BigQuery directly with R---without creating a dataframe

Tags: r, google-bigquery, r-dbi, bigrquery

I'm working with CSV files in an R notebook. To upload the data I'm using a `bash` chunk and `bq` command. I'd like to be able to do it in an R chunk.

I use `bigrquery` and `dbplyr` for my BigQuery work in R. But `bigrquery` and `DBI` don't seem to have methods to allow a disk file to pass through to BigQuery without first creating a dataframe.

Is there a way to do this other than a `bash` chunk or `system` command?

Comment: There are some ways that I found how you can load a CSV file with R into BigQuery. The approaches are the next ones:
[1]https://rdrr.io/cran/bigQueryR/man/bqr_upload_data.html 
[2]https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/batch-loading-data#loading_data_from_local_files 
[3]https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table

Comment: I'm aware of bigqueryR, but it isn't being maintained so I'm reluctant to put it in a pipeline.